Which processes listen to UDP port 7447?
I have six processes, working on UDP port 7447: one server and five clients.
I would like to show all of them, so I tried the commandline command netstat -aon | findstr "7447", but this yielded the following result:
UDP    0.0.0.0:7447           *:*                                    35180

(35180 is the PID of the server process.)
... but what about the client processes, listening to that same port?
One of these client processes has PID 4612, so I use the following commandline command (filtering on PID, not on UDP port):
netstat -aon | findstr "4612"

This gives the following result (I have no idea what UDP port 62102 means):
UDP    0.0.0.0:62102          *:*                                    4612

I thought that netstat -a shows all listening ports, but I don't find the listening port 7447.
Also SysInternal's process explorer seems not to be aware of the listening port of that client application:

How can I see all processes, which are listening to a certain UDP port?
Thanks in advance

Clients and servers are concepts on the application layer, which is off topic here. Usually, only a 'server' listens, and a 'client' connects to the listening server. Also, with few exceptions, a specific port can only be used by a single process.

@Zac67: indeed: the server listens to that port, and the others (clients) are subscribing to it, that's the whole idea. Why then close my question?

The listener ("server") allocates and listens to a "well-known" port for incoming connections (TCP) or datagrams (UDP). The initiator allocates an ephemeral port (the UDP:62102 in your question) and uses it to connect to or send a datagram to the listening port. Since UDP is 'fire and forget', there's no socket connection that netstat could show. At the end of the day, you're asking about applications and host implementations that are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

I begin to see your misconception - let's try an answer.

I think there's a misunderstanding. The only process listening to UDP:0.0.0.0:7447 is the 'server' process.
Also UDP is connection-less. A process sends a datagram from a previously allocated (ephemeral) "socket" (i.e.: transport layer protocol + IP address + port) to another socket.
In a regular client-server construct using UDP, the client would allocate a dynamic/ephemeral socket and use it to send a datagram to a known server socket. In many application protocols (off topic here) the server may respond with another datagram back to the original socket - or to a different socket specified within the datagram. The client may use the same socket for another datagram to the server, or it may allocate a new dynamic socket, depending on the (off-topic) application protocol.
From the perspective of the local UDP/IP stack, these datagrams running back and forth have no relation - each is transported without regard of previous messages (this "connection-less"). Accordingly, the 'connection between port 7447 and 62102' that you are looking for does not exist, thus netstat can't show it to you. If you want to watch what's actually happening you'd need to run a packet capture.
Also note that the 0.0.0.0 address is special, because it means the process is listening on all IP interfaces of the local host (it's specifically different from 127.0.0.1).

Thanks a lot for your answer: the "fire and forget" remark in your comment was a real eye-opener. :-)

I think you mix "port" and "socket" a bit: If the "client may use the same port for another datagram to the server", wouldn't it receive it's own message then, too, or would a bind to the same (or any used) socket address be denied (for obvious security reasons)?

A socket is an IP:port combination - I just wanted to keep it simple. same port (socket) means the previously used dynamic one. The server socket is allocated by the server process, so the client can't have it.
